# Oracle EBS - R12 Form Personalisation

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, oracleforms, oracle-ebs

In oracle EBS Form personalisation

please help me
  - how to find if a field (in my case its Quantity (Qty field in Pricing, Shipping, Addresses , Returns , service and Others tabs)). is changed or not.
  - while click on save we should pop up the message -("update not allowed") **and bring back the OLD quantity back to the field.**

**I am not sure how to check if there is any change happened in the quantity field(which is there in all the tabs ie Pricing , Shipping, Addresses , Returns , service and Others tabs) and  bring back the old quantity back in the quantity field.**

Please help

AT

Comment: Why not use Forms Personalization just to make the field read only?

Comment: Actually.. We need to pop up the message as per the requirement(Business team), and when we do that  its hard to bring the old value back in place  :(

Comment: One other comment: judging by the names of the tabs (pricing, shipping, addresses, returns), I am guessing that this is for the Sales Order form in the Order Management module.  If so, you would be *much* better served by implementing this logic as a _Processing Constraint_ than as a Forms personalization.  Using a Processing Constraint, it would be very easy to pop up a message whenever a user tried to update a certain field.  Plus, Oracle would enforce your logic in API calls to update the Sales Order as well, usually a good thing.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the below code with the below conditions:

**Trigger Event**: `WHEN-VALIDATE-RECORD`

**Trigger Object**: `LINE`

**Condition**:

```
( SELECT ordered_quantity
  FROM oe_order_lines_all
  WHERE line_id = :LINE.LINE_ID )
<> :LINE.ORDERED_QUANTITY
```

**Processing Mode**: `Not in Enter-Query Mode`

#### Action Tab

**Action Type**: `Messages`

**Message Type**: `Error`

**Message Text**: `You cannot change the Ordered Quantity`

Note: You can set the responsibility as per the business scenario.